# How to Implement Java Class in Groovy Script

Tags: java, groovy

I have some java code that I wrote in IntelliJ that I need to implement in Groovy. I understand that Groovy is a subset of Java so sure it shouldn't be too hard to do right?

Can someone guide me on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a instance of your  object and call his methods, if you want to implement it in groovy ?

```
def myObj = new MyJavaClass()
```

And then do something like that :

```
myObj.myMethod()
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Hey, yeah thats what I want to do, essentially, I've written code in IntelliJ, and I want to past that code in groovy in soapui, as I understand that groovy is a subset of Java, but that will give me compilation errors.